# Add Redis Module as a Maven Dependency in Mule

Tags: java, maven, redis, mule

Because the issue reported [here](https://github.com/mulesoft/redis-connector/issues/3), I used the **3.3.1** connector version in a non-maven mule project and worked perfectly.

However, I want to add the redis on a maven mule project. But, the [redis docs](http://mulesoft.github.io/redis-connector/guide/install.html) only gives me 2 options: The `Release` or the `Latest` version. Both cause the issue reported [above](https://github.com/mulesoft/redis-connector/issues/3).

I have tried to change the version to **3.3.1** or **3.3.2** but when I try to start the project, I got the following error:

> Failed to execute goal on project single-sign-on: Could not resolve dependencies for project br.com.xpto:single-sign-on:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.modules:mule-module-redis:jar:3.3.2 -> org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-annotations:jar:3.3.1 -> org.mule.modules:mule-module-annotations:jar:3.3.0 -> org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.3.0 -> javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi: Could not transfer artifact javax.activation:activation:pom:1.1-osgi from/to codehaus-snaphosts (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/): snapshots.repository.codehaus.org

**Question**: Does anyone know how to add the redis dependency on a maven project without being the release or the latest?

**UPDATE**

In order to help you guys understand my problem, I will add my pom.xml below

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>xpto</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule</packaging>
<name>Mule xpto Application</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <mule.version>3.7.0</mule.version>
    <mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-resource</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>mappings/</directory>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <excludeMuleDependencies>false</excludeMuleDependencies>
                <inclusions>
                    <inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-module-redis</artifactId>
                    </inclusion>
                </inclusions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- Mule Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Transports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-redis</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <name>Central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-release</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

So the key points of the pom.xml above are:

**1-** The repositories

```
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
```

**2-** The dependecy

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-redis</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to start the application, got the following error

> BUILD FAILURE
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xpto: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.mycompany:xpto:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: 
>   Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.modules:mule-module-redis:jar:3.3.2 ->
>   org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-annotations:jar:3.3.1 -> 
>   org.mule.modules:mule-module-annotations:jar:3.3.0 -> org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.3.0
>   -> javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi: Could not transfer artifact
>   javax.activation:activation:pom:1.1-osgi from/to codehaus-snaphosts (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/):
>   snapshots.repository.codehaus.org -> [Help 1]

**UPDATE 2**

Executing the command *mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=javax.activation* I got the following output:

> Downloading: http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
>   Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
>   Downloading: http://repository.codehaus.org/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec/1.1-osgi/geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec-1.1-osgi.pom
>   BUILD FAILURE
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xpto: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:xpto:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.modules:mule-module-redis:jar:3.3.2 -> org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-annotations:jar:3.3.1 -> org.mule.modules:mule-module-annotations:jar:3.3.0 -> org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.3.0 -> org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:1.1-osgi: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:1.1-osgi: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:pom:1.1-osgi from/to codehaus-snaphosts (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/): snapshots.repository.codehaus.org -> [Help 1]

Comment: The repository on codehaus.org does not exist anymore they have closed there doors at march of 2015....So the repository definition is simply wrong...

Comment: I have followed the docs of redis-connector and when I put the version to RELEASE or LATEST this error does not occurr. However, I want to use a previous version, for example 3.3.1. When I change the version dependency, I receive this error. I want to know what should I do to achieve that.

Comment: Don't use RELEASE or LATEST you should define the version you need..for example 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Add the following repository to your pom so that `javax/activation/activation/1.1-osgi` can be found:

```
   <repository>
    <id>codehaus-mule-repo</id>
    <name>codehaus-mule-repo</name>
    <url>
        https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
    </url>
    <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
```